# Unhandled promise rejection stripe paymentIntent example

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, unhandled-promise-rejection

I'm trying to setup a stripe payment app using node and express, following the example here:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web

I created the route in my server side app code as indicated, and inserted the client-side code in my html file. I'm trying to create the app without a template engine, just html/css/javascript/node.

```
var response = fetch('/secret').then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(responseJson) {
  var clientSecret = responseJson.client_secret;
  // Call stripe.confirmCardPayment() with the client secret.
});
```

I'm getting the following error:
Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

I'm new to promises and not sure what the syntax with this code should be. Can I add

```
promise1.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Yes, you should add a `.catch(…)` clause, but what is `promise1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, adding a catch method at the end would catch the error(rejected Promise). What you suggested would work.

```
var response = fetch('/secret').then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(responseJson) {
  var clientSecret = responseJson.client_secret;
  // Call stripe.confirmCardPayment() with the client secret.
}).catch(function(err) {
  // Handle error
});
```